# Cassandra exception under load

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We are using Cassandra in production with these following configuration:

- 16 core CPU
- 56 GB Memory
- 4 Nodes
- Secondary disk type: SSD

Drivers version:

```
- Spring data cassandra : 1.5.1
- Spring data cassandra contain cassandra driver core : 3.1.4
- Native protocol : v4
```

Cassandra version:
 - DSE 5.0.5 which uses Cassandra 3.0.11.1485

CPU consuption:

- Node 1 : 80%
- Node 2 : 30%
- Node 3 : 20%
- Node 4 : 40%

Cassandra connection configurations are following:

```
spring.data.cassandra.cluster-name= Test Cluster
spring.data.cassandra.compression= none
spring.data.cassandra.connect-timeout-millis= 5000
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name= event
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=host1,host2,host3,host4
spring.data.cassandra.port= 9042
spring.data.cassandra.max.request.per.connection.local=32768
spring.data.cassandra.max.request.per.connection.remote=2000
spring.data.cassandra.max-core-connection.local=8
spring.data.cassandra.max-core-connection.remote=2
```

Cassandra configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class CassandraConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.cluster-name}")
    public String clusterName;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
    public String keySpace;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
    private String contactpoints;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
    public int port;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.max.request.per.connection.local}")
    public int localRequestConnection;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.max.request.per.connection.remote}")
    public int remoteRequestConnection;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.max.connection.local}")
    public int localConnection;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.max.connection.remote}")
    public int remoteConnection;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.connect-timeout-millis}")
    public int poolTimeoutMillis;

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints(contactpoints);
        cluster.setPort(port);
        cluster.setClusterName(clusterName);
        cluster.setCompressionType(CompressionType.NONE);
        cluster.setPoolingOptions(getCassandraPool());

        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public PoolingOptions getCassandraPool() {
        PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions(); 
        poolingOptions
        .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, localRequestConnection)
        .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, remoteRequestConnection)
        .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 8)
        .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2)
        .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 8)
        .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2)
        .setPoolTimeoutMillis(poolTimeoutMillis);
        return poolingOptions;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter() {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {
        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName(keySpace);
        session.setConverter(converter());
        return session;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
    }
}
```

**What problem we are facing is**:

During normal traffic, everything goes well, but as soon as traffic goes high we get these below error from Cassandra driver:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/105.12.14.114:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:202)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalException(RequestHandler.java:201)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2400(RequestHandler.java:46)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalException(RequestHandler.java:795)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.processRetryDecision(RequestHandler.java:421)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onTimeout(RequestHandler.java:778)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ResponseHandler$1.run(Connection.java:1374)
        at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:581)
        at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:655)
        at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:367)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/105.12.14.114:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onTimeout(RequestHandler.java:772)
        ... 6 more
```

**Edit 1** :

I have around 60 tables similar to below table which is used to accomplish different use-cases

**Cassandra table**.

create table IF NOT EXISTS kspace.count_table
    (source_id bigint, name varchar, date text, pname varchar, ptype varchar, pvalue blob, 
    count counter,unique_count counter, PRIMARY 
    KEY((source_id,name,pname,ptype,date),pvalue))

**Cassandra queries**:

I have different varieties of queries for our different use-case.
Below are  example table queries which resemble our original queries:

- Single query (around 12)
- Batch queries belonging to the same partition
  key (around 30 queries)
- Batch queries belonging to the different
  partition key (around 20 queries)

**Edit 2 :** We are facing this problem after migrating from Apache Cassandra 2.1.8 to DSE version 5.0.5

Comment: Show your table and the query

Comment: The exception isn't Spring-specific, it's a timeout exception.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: a. Do you have any nodes "remote"? If not, guess your remote connection settings are redundant. b. You might want to set LoadBalancingPolicy in your settings, if it is a single DC then work with RoundRobinPolicy and if you have multiple DCs then go with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy and see if that helps. c. Along with load balancing, do look into your partition keys, if in case those are creating hotspots. As per above, one of your nodes has high CPU usage, which can be due to inappropriate load balancing or hot spots.

Comment: We are facing this problem after migrating from Apache Cassandra 2.1.8 to DSE version 5.0.5

Comment: When you say batch on different partition keys, how big are these batches? And more importantly, are using batch to ensure you have consistency across similar data?

Comment: @PatrickMcFadin Thanks for helping. We have solved our problem. The problem was due to `disk throttling `.  For your information, we were having around  200-400 queries in a batch. Reducing batch size solved our problem.